# Can we keep same GCM ID even after app resintallation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to keep a consistent GCM iD even after we re-install our app. as of now its changing if i uninstall the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not.

---

If you are facing problem with identifying the correct device on server, then use device_id as primary id to identify device. Read [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id), how to get device id and store it on server. Now if your registartion id has changed at any time, you have device_id and you can identify your device, and then you should update new registartion id of device.

Comment: Thanks ! device_id seems to be good, however i guess wifi mac id is more reliable than device_id.

Comment: If min sdk version of your app is 2.2 or below, then yes you can go with that. http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000103 is a complete solution for each option which can give you unique identifier for device. They also listed disadvatages for each, so it will help you to choose your target.

Comment: I'm using 4.0 and above. So what do you suggest?

Comment: Then device id is better option.